# How to find which mmap argument is causing [Errno 22] Invalid argument exception?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04, mmap, v4l2

I'm trying to allocate a small buffer for a V4L camera, but I receive

```
mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Can you suggest how to debug and find which is the *invalid argument,* so the `mmap` will succeed?

**MCVE code:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import fcntl
import mmap
import os
import psutil
import v4l2


def alocate_buf(buf):
    print("Trying to allocate a buffer of size {}".format(buf.length))
    print("vd.fileno():", vd.fileno(), type(vd.fileno()))
    print("buf.length:", buf.length, type(buf.length))
    print("buf.m.offset:", buf.m.offset, type(buf.m.offset))
    mm = mmap.mmap(vd.fileno(), buf.length, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE, offset=buf.m.offset)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    print("available memory:", mem.available)

    vd = open("/dev/video3", 'rb+', buffering=0)

    buf = v4l2.v4l2_buffer()
    buf.type = v4l2.V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    buf.memory = v4l2.V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP
    buf.index = 0
    buf.length = 1024

    alocate_buf(buf)
```

**Code run:**

```
$ python find_max_mmap.py
available memory: 6439845888
Trying to allocate a buffer of size 1024
vd.fileno(): 3 <type 'int'>
buf.length: 1024 <type 'long'>
buf.m.offset: 0 <type 'long'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_max_mmap.py", line 30, in <module>
    alocate_buf(buf)
  File "find_max_mmap.py", line 15, in alocate_buf
    mm = mmap.mmap(vd.fileno(), buf.length, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE, offset=buf.m.offset)
mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Linux 4.4.0-64-generic, #85-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
- UVC device: Intel RealSense 410

**Edit 1:**

Note that changing the relevant line to:

```
mm = mmap.mmap(vd.fileno(), buf.length)
```

Still gives:

```
$ python mmap_SO.with_0.py
available memory: 6418022400
Trying to allocate a buffer of size 0
vd.fileno(): 3 <type 'int'>
buf.length: 0 <type 'long'>
buf.m.offset: 0 <type 'long'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mmap_SO.with_0.py", line 30, in <module>
    alocate_buf(buf)
  File "mmap_SO.with_0.py", line 15, in alocate_buf
    mm = mmap.mmap(vd.fileno(), buf.length)
mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Have you tried calling it with just the fileno and zero len?

Comment: Yes, @pvg, see **Edit 1**.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the Python v4l2 module myself, but when testing MMAP vs the USERPTR allocation approaches, I did hit EINVAL at first. My problem turned out to be that I was not setting the image format before calling mmap() on that file descriptor.

Given that I don't see any construction of `v4l2_format()` or `fnctl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_S_FORMAT, ...)` in your code, this seems likely to be your problem as well. If you try setting the format do you still get EINVAL?

To ensure that you specify a resolution and pixel format that is compatible with /dev/video3, you can inspect via `guvcview` or other webcam tool.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `open("/dev/video3", 'rb+', buffering=0)` use `os.open("/dev/video3",os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK)`

Comment: Please explain!